# @Bean annotation not working in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created the Model

```
@Repository
public class Model {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Model(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Model() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Then I created the configuration class with a bean

```
@Component
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Model beanB() {
        Model a=new Model();
        a.setName("Daniel3");
        return a;
    }   
}
```

Then I created the Controller class

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    Model model;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public Model test() {
        return model;
    }

}
```

When I hit the controller url, I am getting the below response

`{"name":null}`

But if I modify configuration class as

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Model beanB() {
        Model a=new Model();
        a.setName("test");
        return a;
    }
```

I get the output as `{"name":"test"}` .
And I am observing the same behaviour when using Autowired Model instead of new Model()

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: What full qualified name of Model class?

Comment: Using the @Repository annotation wrong. Please read the documentation at https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#learn to learn more about what the annotation means and where to use. This is a Model class and should be instantiated with every request cause the state will change.

Comment: In case you are just testing how Bean creation works, @rieckpil answered your question below :)

Comment: You don't need to use `@ResponseBody` when you're using `@RestController`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are registering two different beans of type `Model` as you use `@Repository` on your `Model` class which you shouldn't do as this is used for database repositories. If you remove `@Repository` from your `Model` you'll only have one bean definition and hence get the correct one injected to your controller:

```
// @Repository remove this, should not be used here
public class Model {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Model(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Model() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

The reason it works with `@Primary` is that you then define are order hof importance among all beans of the type `Model`.

Comment: I have a question, that why isn't spring giving error for multiple beans for model, if I don't remove @Repository.

Comment: You can define as many beans of a given type with Spring as you want. Spring won't throw an error if define multiple beans of a type as this is a common use case e.g. multiple `RestTemplate` for each remote system you call and seperate them all either by name or using `@Qualifier("restTemplateOne")`. I can really recommend reading the Spring IoC container documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans

Comment: @rieckpil But shouldn't Spring throw an exception in autowiring when none of the `Model` beans is annotated with `@Primary`? I'm thinking that Spring should not be able to decide which bean candidate to pick. Why did OP get a successful output before adding `@Primary`?

Comment: If you don't use `@Primary` and have two beans of the same type, you can refer to them using their bean name, e.g. `modelB` and `modelA` and Spring will inject the correct for you.

Comment: @rieckpil Oh, okay, so `@Repository class Model` will create a bean named `model`, which matches the name of the variable with `@Autowired` annotation on it, that's why it's selected by Spring. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`@Repository` means you are injecting a bean of type repository in bean factory, further more when you also add `@Bean` annotation it becomes a second bean, so it creates a matter of importance between these two beans and when you add `@Primary` it gave importance to your `@Bean` annotated bean.